# Is Netbeans 6.7 incapable of debugging Groovy closures in a Grails application?

Tags: debugging, grails, netbeans, groovy, closures

It [seems to be possible](http://javasoapbox.blogspot.com/2009/06/whats-netbeans-67-got-for-groovy-and.html) to debug Grails applications in the recently released Netbeans 6.7, even if not directly through the menus. However, is it really so, that it's still not possible to set breakpoints in closures, as hinted in this [thread](http://www.nabble.com/Debugging-Groovy-classes-in-NetBeans-td20653361.html)?

I'm currently quite baffled by this, since I find it hard to believe they still haven't implemented proper debugging support. I am hoping to someone to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 3):

We had luck running

```
grails-debug run-app
```

outside of the IDE and then connecting the IDE to the debug session on port 5055.

And by luck I mean then we stopped using this product because it lacked decent debug capabilities and paid for our IntelliJ licenses.